# Finding MGF of $P(x)$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with pmf $p_X(x)=\frac{|x|+10}{32}$ for $x\in\{1,0,-1\}$. Find the of the mgf $M_X(t)$ of $X$.

I'm not really sure how to go about solving this since there are three distinct values for $X$, rather than a range of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the definition
$$
M_{X}(t)=Ee^{tX}=\sum_{k\in\{-1,0, 1\}}P(X=k) e^{tk}. 
$$